# Assembly * uses * which has a higher version than referenced assembly

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I'm getting the following error:

> Assembly 'Jenkins.Core, Version=2.1.2.22051, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2f531e0c1c11a32b' uses 'Jenkins.Domain, Version=2.1.1.22051, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2f531e0c1c11a32b' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Jenkins.Domain, Version=2.1.1.22017, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2f531e0c1c11a32b'

I tried adding the following bindingRedirect in app.config but nothing changed :(

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Jenkins.Domain" publicKeyToken="2f531e0c1c11a32b" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.1.22051" newVersion="2.1.1.22017"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

These are two nuget packages and yes, I'm guessing the nugets weren't updated together but that's beyond my control (and they are both up to date).

It looks like a very simple application of bindingRedirect but I can't get it to work.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I just ran into the same problem myself. :/

Comment: Same here. Not sure the answer below is applicable

Comment: It doesn't seem like it is possible to redirect to an older version. I had a similar situation with other references, and I ended up having to recompile referencing the older version.

Answer (score -1):

The new version should be the newer version, you are pointing it at the older version, use `newVersion="2.1.1.22051"` instead.

Also make sure the nuget package that imported 2.1.1.22051 is still importing the DLL, you may need to re-install the package or manally change which dll is refrenced by your project in the `/Packages` folder of your solution.

Comment: This doesn't address the posted issue.  OP is obviously using the older version in their own project reference and your suggested solution will not fix the original problem.  You make an assumption that the OP can update their local version of the DLL simply because the third party DLL requires it.  This may not be the case, and wasn't stated in the post.